# How would I be able to give a GUI a username, then have it affect a dummy avatar via changing it to that users avatar?

Tags: roblox, avatar

I'm making a ROBLOX FNaF 6 True Ending, but you can enter player names and make them replace the burning animatronics.

https://www.roblox.com/games/8281431812/d4dj-meme

Pretty much like the game above ^^.

[the thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhp9P.png)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but you could easily do this by creating a remoteevent then firing it after a player enters the required information in a gui

Comment: thanks, but im kinda new to the scripting scene, so it would be polite if you'd put this in a simple video. thanks! ^-^